# Java searching a string

Tags: java, search

I am developing a swing based application.In it,there is a JTable.The data is populated in JTable in two ways-

1. User selects a file(File Chooser etc).Application loads the data into JTable.
2. Application polls for messages on some network parameters.When message arrives, it loads into JTable.

I now want to give Search option to user.When he types any string in jDialog box, application should focus on that specific row where the string matches to data in row of table.When table is populated, TableModel changes.Each row is vector so table is Vectors of Vector.
What data structure will be suitable for this?looping through every row Vector and searching?

Answer (score 2):

The search is done on the table's model - you're vector of vectors. If your doing a freetext search (and don't want to compute an index), your datastructure ist suitable, because you have to test every cell if it contains the search string or matches the pattern. Basically you want to do something like this:

```
List<List<String>> tableModel = getTableModel(); // some magic at the beginning
String searchString = getSearchString();

for (List<String> row:tableModel) {
  for (String cell:row) {
    if (cell.contains(searchString)) {
       // We've found one cell that contains the search string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Thats what i want to do.But wanted to know,if there is any better way.Number of rows in table will vary from 1 to max-200.and each row has 6 fields.

Comment: @Chirota - Don't care about performance if you just have to visit 1200 cells. For larger models, one could consider indexing the input data and using a library like lucene, but that's a lot of effort and definitly not worth it in your scenario.

Comment: I would not worry about efficiency if you're only running up to 1200 comparisons.